# Proper reply for an letter "We will soon contact you for an interview"

Tags: phd, application

I applied for a phd position in a Austrian university. Then I got a mail which said "We will soon contact you for an interview" and I have been waiting for four days now.
Is it appropriate if I ask an update about the interview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polite-packaged rejections look very differently, then they wouldn't promise an interview. They would say some similar: *"We are considering your application"*, *"We forwarded your application to department/leader for further evaluation"* (...until the eternity).

You can be sure that they have the intent to interview you.

You can't be sure, what is the intent of this interview. It might be also a pseudo-interview, where the decision of your application/rejection (second is more common) have been already long made. However doing it in the academian world with foreigners is unlikely.

Sometimes, not even rarely, such administrative tasks have a surprising long wait in the Academia, much longer as it would be realistic on the job market. It is because that world is not so strongly competitive.

The expected value of the time until you get an evaluable answer might be between weeks and months. You can significantly decrease it by asking them, what is now. Of course, you risk by it that you annoy them, what you likely won't do, but this chance is small. It is because probably not your interview is the only task with what they are in delay.

A politely packaged hastening mail could look like so:

1. First you wait so many time which makes obvious that you can already really have a problem. The two weeks mentioned by @Allure seems realistic in this sense also for me.
2. You mention some external circumstances on your side (you need to decide because X depends on it).
3. This external circumstance should be some very different that you have an offer from others, too, and you don't know if you should accept that.

If you have luck, they will think exactly (3). It will even increase your value in their eyes.

Answer (score 2):

4 days is not particularly long. If it's cramping your decision-making - for example if you *really* need to know when the interview is so you can decide on a suitable date to schedule your marriage - then go ahead and ask, but otherwise I would wait a bit longer (up to ~2 weeks).